# WordPress: отключить создание нового "Post ID", если страница в "post-new.php" не заполнена

Tags: php, wordpress

Проект на WordPress.

В разделе **"Постоянные ссылки"** выбрана опция **"/%post_id%/"** (site.ru/123/). ЧПУ формат **"/%postname%/"** (site.ru/title-post/) не подходит, потому что заголовки всегда длинные (соответственно, URL тоже).

Вариант редактировать и сокращать ссылки вручную не подходит, хотелось бы более автоматизированный вариант. Поэтому был выбран формат **"/%post_id%/"** для ссылок.

Ранее числа в ссылках увеличивались не по порядку, а через несколько цифр. На значение "Post ID" влияют все созданные записи, страницы, загружаемые изображения, а также редакции постов (revisions).

**Решение было следующим:** отключить создание "revisions" через functions.php. Это помогло избавиться от лишних "Post ID", но не полностью.

Если зайти на страницу "site.ru/wp-admin/post-new.php", сохранить черновик, посмотреть получившийся "Post ID" (допустим, 250), затем нажать "Добавить новую запись" и потом обновлять страницу несколько раз, то при каждом таком обновлении страницы будет создаваться новое значение "Post ID".

Пост не будет виден в разделе "Записи" (site.ru/wp-admin/edit.php), но при этом в базу данных пост заносится как черновик. И, что самое главное для меня в данной ситуации, - создается много лишних несуществующих значений "Post ID" в ссылках. Таким образом, разбег чисел в ссылках становится очень большим.

Не понимаю, зачем создавать автоматически новый "Post ID", если я просто открыл "site.ru/wp-admin/post-new.php", и не заполнил ни заголовок, ни текст, никуда не нажимал. И при каждом обновлении этой страницы сразу же создается новый "Post ID".

Возможно ли как-то сделать проверку, что, например, если эта страница пустая, то не создавать "Post ID"? Или еще какое-то другое решение?

Отключение функции автосохранения поста (disable autosave) не помогает.
Надеюсь, что я понятно объяснил суть происходящего.

Благодарю заранее за помощь в поиске решения этой задачи.

Comment: "а затем обновлять страницу несколько раз, то при каждом таком обновлении страницы будет создаваться новое значение "Post ID"" - ничего подобного. Так WP себя не ведет. Отключите плагины, смените тему на стандартную, убедитесь, что это не так.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Именно в этом предложении я не совсем правильно выразился. Имел ввиду, что после создания поста мы смотрим самый последний созданный "Post ID". Затем нажимаем "Добавить новую запись" и потом уже обновляем страницу несколько раз. Таким образом, "post ID" был, например, "200". Затем нажимаем "Добавить запись" и уже потом обновляем страницу, например, 10 раз. После сохраняем пост и ID будет уже не 201, а 210.

Comment: То есть открываем "site.ru/wp-admin/post-new.php" и обновляем страницу много раз. После каждого обновления Post ID будет автоматически увеличиваться. Даже если ничего не писать на странице создания поста (заголовок, текст, выбор рубрики и т.д.). Это же не совсем логично получается. Страница пустая, но все равно заносится в базу. В списке на странице "Записи" пост этот не будет показываться. Но Post ID он занимает, и в БД добавляется. Можно ведь до того, как ты ввел хотя бы 1 символ не присваивать пустой странице Post ID.

Comment: WP создаёт в этом случае записи со статусом auto-draft. Так сделано по очень многим причинам. Вы не сможете изменить это поведение, забудьте эту идею.

Comment: Вот неплохое объяснение, почему нельзя отключить auto-draft https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546879/6817117